Testing Coin Flip and Dice Rolling Fallacies with Empirical Data
This is a probability question that confused me for a long time.
Suppose we flip a two-sided fair coin:

Problem A: Are 9 consecutive heads very likely?
Problem B: If we have 8 consecutive heads, is the next flip (i.e. 9th) more likely to be tails?

Mathematically, these questions can be expressed as:
$$\text{Problem A:} \quad  P(H , H,H,H,H, H, H, H, H) = P(H) \cdot P(H) \cdot P(H) \cdot P(H) \cdot P(H) \cdot P(H) \cdot P(H) \cdot P(H) \cdot P(H) = 0.5 ^9 =  0.001953125$$
$$ \text{Problem B:} \quad  P(H |H, H, H, H, H, H, H) = P(H) = 0.5 $$
I use to think that a coin getting 8 consecutive heads is unlikely and a coin getting 9 consecutive heads is even more unlikely. Therefore if a run of 8 has not been interrupted, then a run of 9 is even more likely to be interrupted. However, since each coin flip is independent from the previous flip, the probability is always 0.5.
I wrote an R simulation to observe this.
For Problem A, we can see that the probability for increasing numbers of heads reduces:
# Problem A:

n_simulations <- 100000
outcomes <- c("Heads", "Tails")
count_all_heads <- rep(0, 10)


for (i in 1:10) {
    for (j in 1:n_simulations) {
        flips <- sample(outcomes, size = i, replace = TRUE)
        if (all(flips == "Heads")) {
            count_all_heads[i] <- count_all_heads[i] + 1
        }
    }
}


percentages <- (count_all_heads / n_simulations) * 100

for (i in 1:10) {
    print(paste("Percentage of", i, "consecutive 'Heads' in", n_simulations, "simulations:", percentages[i], "%"))
}

[1] "Percentage of 1 consecutive 'Heads' in 1e+05 simulations: 50.115 %"
[1] "Percentage of 2 consecutive 'Heads' in 1e+05 simulations: 24.899 %"
[1] "Percentage of 3 consecutive 'Heads' in 1e+05 simulations: 12.688 %"
[1] "Percentage of 4 consecutive 'Heads' in 1e+05 simulations: 6.194 %"
[1] "Percentage of 5 consecutive 'Heads' in 1e+05 simulations: 3.138 %"
[1] "Percentage of 6 consecutive 'Heads' in 1e+05 simulations: 1.575 %"
[1] "Percentage of 7 consecutive 'Heads' in 1e+05 simulations: 0.8 %"
[1] "Percentage of 8 consecutive 'Heads' in 1e+05 simulations: 0.399 %"
[1] "Percentage of 9 consecutive 'Heads' in 1e+05 simulations: 0.212 %"
[1] "Percentage of 10 consecutive 'Heads' in 1e+05 simulations: 0.093 %"

Whereas for Problem B, the conditional probability of heads stays the same (regardless of the past):
#Problem B
n <- 10000
outcomes <- c("Heads", "Tails")
coin_flips <- sample(outcomes, size = n, replace = TRUE)

count_runs <- rep(0, 10)
count_heads_after_run <- rep(0, 10)

for (i in 1:10) {
  for (j in 1:(n-i)) {
    if (all(coin_flips[j:(j+i-1)] == "Heads")) {
      count_runs[i] <- count_runs[i] + 1
      if (coin_flips[j+i] == "Heads") {
        count_heads_after_run[i] <- count_heads_after_run[i] + 1
      }
    }
  }
}

percentages <- (count_heads_after_run / count_runs) * 100

for (i in 1:10) {
  print(paste("Percentage of times that 'Heads' follows a run of", i, "'Heads':", percentages[i], "%"))
}

[1] "Percentage of times that 'Heads' follows a run of 1 'Heads': 49.9397947019338 %"
[1] "Percentage of times that 'Heads' follows a run of 2 'Heads': 49.9689598961859 %"
[1] "Percentage of times that 'Heads' follows a run of 3 'Heads': 50.0020038313255 %"
[1] "Percentage of times that 'Heads' follows a run of 4 'Heads': 50.06492153311 %"
[1] "Percentage of times that 'Heads' follows a run of 5 'Heads': 50.1056608606557 %"
[1] "Percentage of times that 'Heads' follows a run of 6 'Heads': 49.8817815834878 %"
[1] "Percentage of times that 'Heads' follows a run of 7 'Heads': 49.9359467076608 %"
[1] "Percentage of times that 'Heads' follows a run of 8 'Heads': 49.8460749102104 %"
[1] "Percentage of times that 'Heads' follows a run of 9 'Heads': 49.9227997941328 %"
[1] "Percentage of times that 'Heads' follows a run of 10 'Heads': 51.0309278350515 %"

My Question: I now want to repeat this analysis for a dice rolling problem.
Suppose there a single 6 sided (fair) die. We want to keep rolling this die until we observe two consecutive 6's. If we treat this problem as a Discrete Time Markov Chain, we can find out the expected number of rolls needed to observe two consecutive 6's using First Step Analysis:

State 0: No six has been rolled yet.
State 1: One six has been rolled.
State 2: Two consecutive sixes have been rolled.

Denote the expected number of rolls to reach state 2 from state i as E(i). We are interested in finding E(0).
$$E(0) = 1 + \frac{1}{6}E(1) + \frac{5}{6}E(0)$$
$$E(1) = 1 + \frac{1}{6}E(2) + \frac{5}{6}E(0)$$
$$E(2) = 0$$.
Solving via substitution:
$$E(1) = 1 + \frac{5}{6}E(0)$$
$$E(0) = 1 + \frac{1}{6}(1 + \frac{5}{6}E(0)) + \frac{5}{6}E(0)$$
$$E(0) = 42$$
This can be verified using an R simulation:
roll_until_two_sixes <- function() {
  count <- 0
  last_roll <- 0     
  while(TRUE) {
    roll <- sample(1:6, 1)
    count <- count + 1      
    if(roll == 6 && last_roll == 6) {
      break
    last_roll <- roll
  }  
  return(count)
}   
num_rolls <- numeric(1000)  
for(i in 1:1000) {
  num_rolls[i] <- roll_until_two_sixes()
}    
average_rolls <- mean(num_rolls)
> average_rolls
[1] 41.546

Based on this analysis, I wanted to ask a similar question. Is it possible to derive an equation for:

What is the probability of getting (6,6) in $n$ number of dice rolls? ($n >2 $)
What is the probability of getting (6,6) in $n$ number of dice rolls given that (6,6) has not occurred in $m$ rolls ($n>m$)

If we denote rolling a (6,6) as $E$, I am curious to know if:
$$P(E =m+n) = P(E = n + m| E \notin {1, ... , m})$$
Can someone please help me analyze this? We will reach a similar conclusion as the coin toss problem?
Thanks!

This is quite long.

Without reading the whole thing, does $(6,6)$ refer to consecutive $6's$ with an ordinary fair die?  If so, it's easy to count the $6-$character strings with no double $6's$.  After all, each such string begins with either $X$ or $6X$ where $X$ denotes any value other than $6$.

@ lulu: thank you for reading ... I agree its quite long...I can cut the length of the question in half ... but I wanted to show everyone my mathematical logic/thoughts as to what lead me to ask this question

But I'm afraid the question gets lost.  Aside from shortening the post, I suggest starting with the question, so people know what you are asking.  You can have a Background and Context section afterwards.

Should also say that your first question doesn't really make sense.  For the $9H$ question, you don't specify the number of flips.  As in my prior comment, it's easy to count the binary strings of fixed length without $9$ consecutive $H's$ (well, not as easy as the other problem, but still).  And for the other, you need to say what you mean.  If you are assuming independence then of course the next toss, like all the tosses, is a $50-50$ affair.  But if you think the coin might be weighted, then seeing all those $H's$ might change your assessment of the probabilities.

With regards to the coin example, your events are very badly labeled.  You have used the same name for different events.  It ought to have been something more along the lines of $\Pr(H_1\cap H_2\cap H_3) = \Pr(H_1)\Pr(H_2)\Pr(H_3)$ where $H_i$ is the event that the $i$'th coin flip is heads.

Not an answer to your main question, but here's an excellent video that gives an elegant shortcut and generalization to the first-step analysis part of your question (which you already solved for your specific case): https://youtube.com/watch?v=t8xqMxlZz9Y

“If we denote rolling a (6,6) as $E$,” then $E$ is an event (albeit a poorly defined one—does it describe rolling (6,6) in the first two rolls, once or more in the first $n$ rolls, or something else?). An event $E$ is not a number and it is nonsense to write $E=m+n$.

What does “getting (6,6) in $n$ rolls” mean? If $n=6$, which of the following sequences of rolls gets (6,6) in 6 rolls? 111166; 166111; 661166; 666166; 116661?


What is the probability of getting $(6,6)$ in $n$ number of dice rolls? ($n >2 $)?

The required probability $p_n$ is equal to $1-q_n$, where $q_n$ is the probability of the complement
event. The probability $q_n$ is equal to $\frac {Q_n}{6^n}$, where $Q_n$ is the number of words of length $n$ over the alphabet $\{1,2,\dots,6\}$ containing no subword "$66$", and $6^n$ is the number of all words of length $n$ over the alphabet $\{1,2,\dots,6\}$. But $Q_n=R_n+S_n$, where $R_n$ is the number of these subwords ended by $6$ and $S_n$ be the number of the remaining words. Then $R_1=1$, $S_1=5$, and $R_{n+1}=S_n$, $S_{n+1}=5(R_n+S_n)$ for any natural $n$. That is, $S_2=30$ and
$S_{n+1}=5(S_n+S_{n-1})$ for any natural $n\ge 2$. Then $S_n=C_1\lambda_1^n+C_2\lambda_2^n$, where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are some constants and $\lambda_{1,2}=\frac{5\pm 3\sqrt{5}}2$ are the roots of the characteristic equation $\lambda^2-5\lambda-5=0$ of the recurrence. To find the coefficients $C_1$ and $C_2$, we have to solve the system
$$
\begin{cases}
C_1\lambda_1+C_2\lambda_2=5 \\
C_1\lambda_1^2+C_2\lambda_2^2=30.
\end{cases}
$$
It follows that for any natural $n$ we have  $$S_n=\frac 1{6\cdot 2^n}\cdot \left(
(3+\sqrt{5})(5+3\sqrt{5})^n+(3-\sqrt{5})(5-3\sqrt{5})^n\right).$$
and $Q_n=R_n+S_n=\frac {S_{n+1}}{5}$.

What is the probability of getting $(6,6)$ in $n$ number of dice rolls given that (6,6) has not occurred in $m$ rolls ($n>m$)

The answer to this question is similar to that to the previous. Namely, the required probability $p'_n$ is equal to $1-q'_n$, where $q_n$ is the probability of the complement event. The probability $q'_n$ is equal to $\frac {Q_n}{W_n}$, where $W_n$ is the number of words of length $n$ over the alphabet $\{1,2,\dots,6\}$ with the prefix of length $m$ containing no subword "$66$". Clearly, $W_n=Q_m\cdot 6^{n-m}$.

If we denote rolling a $(6,6)$ as $E$, I am curious to know if:
$$P(E =m+n) = P(E = n + m| E \notin \{1, ... , m\})$$

As I understood this question, we have
$$P(E =m+n)=1-q_{m+n}=1-\frac {Q_{m+n}}{6^{m+n}}=1-\frac {S_{m+n+1}}{5\cdot 6^{m+n}}=$$
$$1-\frac{\frac 1{6\cdot 2^{m+n+1}}\cdot \left(
(3+\sqrt{5})(5+3\sqrt{5})^{m+n+1}+(3-\sqrt{5})(5-3\sqrt{5})^{m+n+1}\right)}
{5\cdot 6^{m+n}}=$$
$$1-\frac 1{5\cdot 12^{m+n+1}}\cdot \left(
(3+\sqrt{5})(5+3\sqrt{5})^{m+n+1}+(3-\sqrt{5})(5-3\sqrt{5})^{m+n+1}\right)\approx$$
$$ 1-\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}5\cdot \left(\frac{5+3\sqrt{5}}{12}\right)^{m+n+1}.$$
and
$$P(E = n + m| E \notin \{1, ... , m\})=1-q'_{n+m}=$$ $$1-\frac {Q_{m+n}}{W_{m+n}}=
1-\frac {Q_{m+n}}{Q_m\cdot 6^n}=1-\frac {S_{m+n+1}}{S_{m+1}\cdot 6^n}=$$
$$1- \frac{\frac 1{6\cdot 2^{m+n+1}}\cdot \left((3+\sqrt{5})(5+3\sqrt{5})^{m+n+1}+(3-\sqrt{5})(5-3\sqrt{5})^{m+n+1}\right)}
{\frac 1{6\cdot 2^{m+1}}\cdot \left(
(3+\sqrt{5})(5+3\sqrt{5})^{m+1}+(3-\sqrt{5})(5-3\sqrt{5})^{m+1}\right)\cdot 6^n}=$$
$$1- \frac 1{12^n}\cdot \frac{ (3+\sqrt{5})(5+3\sqrt{5})^{m+n+1}+(3-\sqrt{5})(5-3\sqrt{5})^{m+n+1}}
{(3+\sqrt{5})(5+3\sqrt{5})^{m+1}+(3-\sqrt{5})(5-3\sqrt{5})^{m+1}}\approx$$
$$ 1-\left(\frac{5+3\sqrt{5}}{12}\right)^n.$$
So, it looks more natural to compare $P(E = n + m| E \notin \{1, ... , m\})$ and
$P(E=n)$ instead of $P(E =m+n)$, but even in this case I expect that the complement
$$1-P(E = n + m| E \notin \{1, ... , m\})\approx \left(\frac{5+3\sqrt{5}}{12}\right)^n$$ is asymptotically a bit smaller than the complement $$1-P(E=n)\approx \frac{3+\sqrt{5}}5\cdot \left(\frac{5+3\sqrt{5}}{12}\right)^{n+1},$$
because $\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}5\cdot \frac{5+3\sqrt{5}}{12}=1.021\dots$ is a bit bigger than $1$.

@ Alex Ravsky: thank you so much! Looking forward for the rest of your answer!

@stats_noob I completed my answer. I hope it contains no errors.
